# "unity symbol" from Feller's "An Introduction to Probability"

Tags: probability, notation

I am wondering if anyone knows the name or source of the symbol shown below from page 22 of the Second Edition of Feller's "An Introduction to Probability" Volume I.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to ask this at tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: I cropped and reduced the size of your images to make the post more readable on a larger variety of platforms. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to be $\mathfrak{S}$, the Fraktur S.

Detexify is a great tool for things like this!

Comment: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html